# Mongoose - Finding Documents based on the IDs in an Array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array of mongoIDs like this

```
arrayOfIDs = ['mongoID1','mongoID2','mongoID3']
```

These are mongo-ids of documents in my collection.

Now by taking the an array of those mongoIDs ie ['mongoID1','mongoID2','mongoID3'], I need to query on each of the document specified by those ids, by using its _id and deal with its data independently in my code logic. *As an example for simplicity, I have just 'printed' the output ie res.json(doc.name)*.

I need something like this below If at all it does exist in Mongoose/MongoDB

```
Shop.find({'_id':['mongoID1','mongoID2','mongoID3']})
    .exec()
    .then(doc =>{
       res.json(doc.name)
    })
```

I know I can use a loop for this case, like this,

```
for(id of arrayOfIDs){
    Shop.find({'_id': id})
        .exec()
        .then(doc =>{
           res.json(doc.name)
        })
}
```

But this involves querying the database multiple times based on the lenght of arrayOfIDs, something I don't want. I would like to have a native mongodb solution that just pass the Ids in mongodb query like in my example above.

Can you please show me how this can be achieved?

Comment: use `$in` like this `{'_id': { $in: ['mongoID1','mongoID2','mongoID3'] } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$in` operator.

```js
{ _id: { $in: ["mongoID1", "mongoID2", "mongoID3"] } }
```

If the type of `_id` is `ObjectId` then you need to convert them to `ObjectId` before passing it

```js
{
  _id: {
    $in: [
      mongoose.Types.ObjectId("mongoID1"),
      mongoose.Types.ObjectId("mongoID2"),
      mongoose.Types.ObjectId("mongoID3"),
    ],
  },
}
```